# What are recent discoveries with Earth-based radar telescopes?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, radar

The [Wikipedia article on radar astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_astronomy) lists a few important discoveries using radar technology in general, i.e. also using space-crafts:

> The following is a list of planetary bodies that have been observed by this means:
>
> - Mercury - Improved value for the distance from the earth observed (GR test). Rotational period, libration, surface mapping, esp. of polar regions.
> - Venus - first radar detection in 1961. Rotation period, gross surface properties. The Magellan mission mapped the entire planet using a radar altimeter.
> - Earth - numerous airborne and spacecraft radars have mapped the entire planet [...]
> - Mars - Mapping of surface roughness from Arecibo Observatory. The Mars Express mission carries a ground-penetrating radar.
> - Jupiter System - Galilean satellites
> - Saturn System - Rings and Titan from Arecibo Observatory, mapping of Titan's surface and observations of other moons from the Cassini spacecraft.

I am interested in **recent discoveries (and scientific references) with Earth-based radar observatories** such as the [Arecibo Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory), the [Goldstone Deep Space Communications Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_Deep_Space_Communications_Complex), [RT-70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RT-70), [Pluton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluton_(complex)), [Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network) and any other one I missed.

Here "discovery" is meant in the wider sense, i.e. the gain of scientific knowledge. The discovery of a new object would be such a discovery, but the mapping of a known object would also be a discovery.

#### References

- [What will succeed the Arecibo Observatory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39948/what-will-succeed-the-arecibo-observatory)
- [How did Arecibo detect methane lakes on Titan, and image Saturn's rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33023/how-did-arecibo-detect-methane-lakes-on-titan-and-image-saturns-rings?rq=1)