# First satellite of an asteroid (or double asteroid) ever imaged by delay-Doppler radar?

Tags: observational-astronomy, asteroids, radio-astronomy, history, radar

In comments about my previous bounty on the Space SE question [Which deep-space spacecraft flew closest by Earth during a gravitational assist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55516/12102), I started to look at the Galileo mission and ran across the following factoid. From [here](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/%7Ejs/ast121/lectures/ida_dactyl.html) for example:

> On August 28, 1993 Galileo came within 2,400 kilometers of Ida, the second asteroid ever encountered by a spacecraft. They passed each other at a relative velocity of 12.4 km/sec (28,000 mph). At the time of the encounter, Ida and Galileo were 441 million kilometers from the Sun.
>
> The greatest discovery from the Galileo fly-by was that Ida has a natural satellite. The moon has been named Dactyl by the International Astronomical Union. **Dactyl is the first natural satellite of an asteroid ever discovered and photographed.** The tiny moon is about 1.2 by 1.4 by 1.6 km across.

From Wikipedia's [243_Ida; Discoveries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/243_Ida#Discoveries):

> The discovery of Ida's moon Dactyl, **the first confirmed satellite of an asteroid**, provided additional insights into Ida's composition.<sup>36</sup>
>
> <sup>36</sup>Chapman, Clark R. (October 1996). "S-Type Asteroids, Ordinary Chondrites, and Space Weathering: The Evidence from Galileo's Fly-bys of Gaspra and Ida". Meteoritics. 31 (6): 699–725. https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996M%26PS...31..699C/abstract and https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1945-5100.1996.tb02107.x

[Delay-Doppler radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_Doppler) can also generate images of (rotating) asteroids and detect and image any satellites they may have. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What was the first satellite of an asteroid (or double asteroid) imaged by delay-Doppler radar?

---

From [this answer to *What causes "North-South ambiguity" when doppler radar imaging a planet surface equator?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30267/7982) in Astronomy SE (see also [What is the physical geometry of this apparent "eclipse" of a tiny moon of Asteroid Florence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22480/7982))

> **Left:** A very slow GIF from Emily Lakdawalla's [How radio telescopes get "images" of asteroids](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2010/2462.html)
>
> **Right:** A radar image shows asteroid 3122 Florence and tiny echoes from its two moons. [Here is an animation](https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/images/news/florence.p5us.1Hz.s382.sep01.gif) that shows them more clearly. The direction of the radar illumination (and thus the direction toward Earth) is at the top." From [here](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/asteroid-florence-has-two-moons/). NASA / Jet Propulsion Laboratory. This is a small subset of the frames contained in the original 36 MB GIF, and the size has been decreased by a factor of 2 in order to fit in SE's 2 MB limit. From the question [What is the physical geometry of this apparent "eclipse" of a tiny moon of Asteroid Florence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22480/7982)
>
> **Note:** These two images do not necessarily have the same orientation.
>
> [image: Delay-Doppler Imaging Emily Lakdawalla] [image]

Comment: `+1` Tough question! I tried a quick 5min search for digging up, found nearly nothing! I'll keep trying tho :3

Comment: There are also other ways to find asteroid satellites.  On Mar 5 1977, Paul Maley detected a satellite of 6 Hebe during an asteroid occultation.  He unofficially named it Jebe, as in heebie-jeebie.  It was the first modern day suggestion that asteroids could have satellites.

Comment: @John Indeed! Measuring stellar occultations by asteroids, especially with a closely spaced array of portable telescopes is now a very important technique (cf. [Winking Stars Help Map Asteroids  — And Discover A New Moonlet](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/how-winking-stars-map-asteroids/)), but I don't know anything about it's early history and firsts. Maybe that topic can benefit from a new question?